# Existence of a particular function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given positive integers $n,d,\ell\ge1$ such that $n\ge 1+(d-1)\ell$, I must find a a function
$$
a=a(n,d,\ell),
$$
such that
\begin{align*}
0< a(n,d,\ell)&<1,\\
\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)&\le a(n,d,\ell),
\end{align*}
for all $n,d,\ell\ge1,\ n\ge1+(d-1)\ell.$

I've been able to solve only the case $\ell=1$. In such a case, the function
$$
a(n,d,1)=\frac{n-d}{n-d+1}
$$
satisfy the requests.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any additional context to this problem, that might serve as inspiration? :)

Comment: @antkam Unfortunately no. I can add as an edit some observation I made that could be useful in order to construct the function $a=a(n,d,\ell)$

Comment: What is wrong with using a constant function $a(n, d, l) = 0.5$?

Comment: @silversilva It doesn't work, since the fraction $\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}$ is strictly greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $a(n, d, l) = \frac {1} {b(n-d, \ell)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma(n+1)} {\Gamma(d+1)}$ where $b(c, l) = \Gamma(3+ \frac {c \cdot \ell} {\ell-1})$. This function satisifies the constraint since:

\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)&=\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)} \cdot \frac {1} {b(n-1-(d-1), \ell)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma(n)} {\Gamma(d)} \\
&\le \frac{n}{1 + (d-1)\ell-(d-1)(\ell-1)} \cdot \frac {1} {b(n-d, \ell)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma(n)} {\Gamma(d)} \ \textit{(Since $n\ge 1+(d-1)\ell$)}\\
&\le \frac{n}{1 + (d-1)} \cdot \frac {1} {b(n-d, \ell)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma(n)} {\Gamma(d)} \\
&\le \frac{n}{d} \cdot \frac {1} {b(n-d, \ell)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma(n)} {\Gamma(d)} \\
&\le \frac {1} {b(n-d, \ell)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma(n+1)} {\Gamma(d+1)} \\
&\le a(n, d, l)
\end{align*}

Clearly $a(n,d,l)>0$ since gamma function is always positive for positive argument. To prove $a(n,d,l)<1$, let us prove the following claim:
\begin{equation*}
n < 2 + \frac {(n-d) \cdot \ell} {\ell-1}
\end{equation*}
Proof of claim:
\begin{align*}
n &\ge 1 + (d-1)\ell \\
n-n\ell &\ge 1 + d\ell -\ell -n\ell \\
n(1-\ell) &\ge 1-\ell - (n-d)\ell \\
n &\le 1- \frac {(n-d)\ell} {1-\ell} \\
n &\le 1+ \frac {(n-d)\ell} {\ell-1} \\
\implies n &< 2 + \frac {(n-d)\ell} {\ell-1}
\end{align*}

From the above claim,we get $n +1 < 3 + \frac {(n-d)\ell} {\ell-1}$ which implies that $\frac {\Gamma(n+1)} {b(n-d, l)} = \frac {\Gamma(n+1)} {\Gamma(3 + \frac {(n-d) \cdot \ell} {\ell-1})}  < 1$. Hence $a(n, d, l) = \frac {1} {b(n-d, \ell)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma(n+1)} {\Gamma(d+1)} < 1$

Comment: Really good answer. Any chance to obtain a function with all these requests and such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a(n,d,\ell)=1,$$ and that converges more quickly to 1 than the fuction you found?

Comment: My function converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. It is hard to create a function with gamma functions that converge to $1$ as a variable tends to infinity. I will give it a try though.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit bulky, but I found a solution. TL;DR, for all $\ell>1$, you can have: $$a(n,d,\ell)= {n!\prod_{g=0}^{\operatorname{floor}(\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})}(1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1}+g(\ell-2))\over1+(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}(n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1))}$$
This works for all $\ell>1$, but if $\ell>2$, then you could "simplify" it to$$a(n,d,\ell)=\frac{n!(\frac{n-d\ell+d+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$

The way I derived this answer was by considering your condition that$$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)\leq a(n,d,\ell)$$ I noticed it looked a lot like recursion because if you have a working set of positive integers $(n,d,\ell)$ that satisfy $n\geq1+(d-1)\ell$, and if $d\geq2$, then $(n-1,d-1,\ell)$ also satisfies that condition. The proof for that is trivial, but we needed this information to realize that$$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)\leq a(n,d,\ell)$$ $$\Rightarrow$$ $$\frac{n-1}{n-1-(d-2)(\ell-1)}a(n-2,d-2,\ell)\leq a(n-1,d-1,\ell)$$

So, initially I thought it would be an exponential, but that led me nowhere, so I looked harder at the condition $n\geq1+(d-1)\ell$ a little more. I focused at the graph of $1\leq d\leq\frac{n+\ell-1}{\ell}$ in cartesian coordinates to find patterns. I used $d$ as the $y$-axis, and $n$ as the $x$-axis, but that's besides the point. I chose this space because $n$ and $d$ would be changing by $-1$ while $\ell$ wouldn't change at all. Since you need the function to be within the bounds of $0$ and $1$, I knew that the line $d=\frac{n+\ell-1}{\ell}$ would have to be where $a(n,d,\ell)=1$ because $n$ and $d$ had to decrease by a factor of at least $\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{n}$ every step down and to the left.

From here, I knew that the inverse was true, that the function would increase by at most $\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}$ every step up and to the right, so I derived the numerator of our function$$\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}\frac{n-h}{n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1)}\Rightarrow{n!\over(n-d)!\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}(n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1))}$$
Remember that we need the line $d=\frac{n+\ell-1}{\ell}$ to be 1, and we move up and to the right by one step each. So we need to divide our numerator by where that line and $d=n+n_0-d_0$ meet where $n_0$ and $d_0$ are arbitrary inputs (it'll cancel out later). The two lines intersect at $(1+\frac{n_0\ell-d_0\ell}{\ell-1},1+\frac{n_0-d_0}{l-1})$.

All we have to do now is take our numerator and replace $n$ and $d$ with $1+\frac{n_0\ell-d_0\ell}{\ell-1}$ and $1+\frac{n_0-d_0}{\ell-1}$ respectively, resulting in the denominator being:$${\frac{(1+\frac{n_0\ell-d_0\ell}{\ell-1})!}{((1+\frac{n_0\ell-d_0\ell}{\ell-1})-(1+\frac{n_0-d_0}{\ell-1}))!}\over\prod_{h=0}^{(1+\frac{n_0-d_0}{l-1})-1}(1+\frac{n_0\ell-d_0\ell}{\ell-1}-h-((1+\frac{n_0-d_0}{l-1})-1-h)(\ell-1))}$$
After some simplification, we get$${(1+\frac{n_0\ell-d_0\ell}{\ell-1})!\over(n_0-d_0)!\prod_{g=0}^{\frac{n_0-d_0}{l-1}}(1+\frac{n_0-d_0}{\ell-1}+g(\ell-2))}$$
which is now our denominator.

We have a lot of junk right now, so lets put them together to see what we can cancel out.$${{n!\over(n-d)!\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}(n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1))}\over{(1+\frac{n_0\ell-d_0\ell}{\ell-1})!\over(n_0-d_0)!\prod_{g=0}^{\frac{n_0-d_0}{l-1}}(1+\frac{n_0-d_0}{\ell-1}+g(\ell-2))}}$$
It turns out that $n_0$ and $d_0$ can be replaced with just $n$ and $d$, and the proof is trivial. That lets us simplify a little bit so we get our (almost) final answer of:$$a(n,d,\ell)= {n!\prod_{g=0}^{\frac{n-d}{\ell-1}}(1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1}+g(\ell-2))\over(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}(n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1))}$$
The reason we're not done yet is because the product has a fractional upper bound. That allows it to reach greater than 1. To fix this, we add the floor function to the upper product bound so that it truly matches what we want to do. We'll also add a $+1$ denominator so that the range is exactly less than one if the numerator and denominator happen to be the same.$$a(n,d,\ell)= {n!\prod_{g=0}^{\operatorname{floor}(\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})}(1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1}+g(\ell-2))\over1+(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}(n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1))}$$ That is our **final** answer. We could make it continuous. Although I wasn't able to simplify it by hand to get rid of the product sign, Wolfram Alpha helped plenty. This gives the other final answer of$$a(n,d,\ell)=\frac{n!(\frac{n-d\ell+d+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$ where $z!$ is shorthand for $z!=\Gamma(z+1)$ and $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function, which is continuous by definition.

Let's see how it tests under the conditions, shall we? Let's start with the easy bit where $$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)\leq a(n,d,\ell)$$
We'll evaluate the left side. Let's start with simplifying the function by substituting the inputs to get $$a(n-1,d-1,\ell)=\frac{(n-1)!(\frac{(n-1)-(d-1)\ell+(d-1)+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{(n-1)-(d-1)\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{(n-1)\ell-(d-1)\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{(n-1)-(d-1)}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
We'll get rid of those pesky parentheses to get $$\frac{(n-1)!(\frac{n-1-d\ell+\ell+d-1+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-1-d\ell+\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-\ell-d\ell+\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-1-d+1}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
We'll follow up with some reduction and necessary factoring to get what we need: $$\frac{(n-1)!(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{2+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
Since this is only the first half of the left side, we need to multiply by $\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}$. So we now have $$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)=\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}\frac{(n-1)!(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{2+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
We'll notice that $n(n-1)!$ is just $n!$, so we can cancel that part out plain and simple.$$\frac{1}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}\frac{n!(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{2+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
This next step took me a few seconds to see but let's notice the converse of that exact statement but for $(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2})!$. We'll also bring that $\frac{1}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}$ up to the top half. So, now we have $$\frac{n!(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2}-1)!(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2})\frac{(\ell-2)^{2+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
We can cancel out a $n-(d-1)(\ell-1)$ and a $\ell-2$ to get $$\frac{n!(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2}-1)!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
Now for our last step. That middle term, $(\frac{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}{\ell-2}-1)!$, looks kinda weird with that $-1$ in there. We'll do some un-weirding to get the final product. $$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)=\frac{n!(\frac{n-d\ell+d+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
But, is it true for our function that it meets the condition we had? $$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)\leq a(n,d,\ell)$$
Well, we know what the right side is, and we now know what the left side is, so we'll plug them in: $$\frac{n!(\frac{n-d\ell+d+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}\leq\frac{n!(\frac{n-d\ell+d+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$
To see it more clearly, let me cancel some terms out from both sides: $$1\leq1$$ which is true. Therefore, our original function $$a(n,d,\ell)=\frac{n!(\frac{n-d\ell+d+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$ satisfies the condition that $$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-1,d-1,\ell)\leq a(n,d,\ell)$$

The second condition we'll look at is the condition that $0<a(n,d,\ell)<1$ where $n\geq1+\ell(d-1)$. To do this, we need to notice that, if $\ell\geq1$, then  $n\leq1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1}$ and $d\leq1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1}$. The proof for this is trivial. We use this fact to our advantage by remembering the (very) crude formulas for our numerator and denominator:$$a(n,d,\ell)=\frac{\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}\frac{n-h}{n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1)}}{1+\prod_{g=0}^{(1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1}\frac{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g-((1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1-g)(\ell-1)}}$$
It is trivial to see that for any arbitrary $t\geq0$, $$0<\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}\frac{n-h}{n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1)}\leq\prod_{g=0}^{d+t-1}\frac{n+t-g}{n+t-g-(d+t-1-g)(\ell-1)}$$
This gives us all we need to know. We know that $n\leq1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1}$ and $d\leq1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1}$, but we also know that $n\leq n+t$ and $d\leq d+t$ for *any* $t\geq0$ (not just integers). Then we can safely say that $$\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}\frac{n-h}{n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1)}\leq\prod_{g=0}^{(1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1}\frac{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g-((1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1-g)(\ell-1)}$$
With that out of the way, we have only proven that $0<a(n,d,\ell)\leq1$, or so it may seem. In our original function $a(n,d,\ell)$, we see in the denominator that we added a one. By adding one to the denominator, we ensure that the numerator is *strictly* less than the denominator. In math terms, $a\leq b\Rightarrow a<b+1\Rightarrow\frac{a}{b+1}<1$. Just replace $a=\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}\frac{n-h}{n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1)}$ and $b=\prod_{g=0}^{(1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1}\frac{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g-((1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1-g)(\ell-1)}$ to get back to our original (crude) function $$a(n,d,\ell)=\frac{\prod_{h=0}^{d-1}\frac{n-h}{n-h-(d-1-h)(\ell-1)}}{1+\prod_{g=0}^{(1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1}\frac{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})-g-((1+\frac{n-d}{\ell-1})-1-g)(\ell-1)}}$$
We already simplified that previously, so therefore we have proven that $0<a(n,d,\ell)<1$ given $$a(n,d,\ell)=\frac{n!(\frac{n-d\ell+d+1}{\ell-2})!(\ell-2)^{1+\frac{n-d\ell}{\ell-1}}}{(1+\frac{n\ell-d\ell}{\ell-1})!(\frac{n-d}{(\ell-1)(\ell-2)}-\frac{\ell-2}{\ell-3})!+1}$$

This function meets all your given conditions.

Comment: Your answer shows a lot of effort, however I'm troubled by how you derived the function $a=a(n,d,\ell)$. In fact, it seems to me that you have assumed for example that  $$\frac{n}{n-(d-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-2,d-2,\ell)\leq a(n-1,d-1,\ell)$$ which is not the case, indeed the right condition is $$\frac{n-1}{n-1-(d-1-1)(\ell-1)}a(n-2,d-2,\ell)\leq a(n-1,d-1,\ell).$$ Other things that bother me are some fraction inside factorial. Of course I think you just forgot to put the floor or ceiling functions.

Comment: I had meant to put that as the condition. It was a typo I overlooked. You can see this is what I meant to put because when I derived the numerator, I subtracted the index of the product from $n$ and $d-1$. Also, I did not forget to put floor or ceiling function in the factorial. I assumed the factorial function was the shorthand for $z!=\Gamma(z+1)$, where $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function, which is continuous. It is only required for the product index to have the floor function because index is discrete, and it traditionally rounds where $\Gamma(z+1)$ doesn't have to worry about that.

Comment: Oh ok, I see it now. Besides the fact that this function is kind of bulky, is there any chance you could provide formal and complete details showing that such a function satisfy the two requests. Also there is any chance for a more simple function to solve the problem? Maybe even one that is not the best possible for numerical accuracy, but it has a more simple form?

Comment: I could provide details on how the function meets the requirements, but I do not think I can provide a simpler solution (if such existed). How should I provide it for you?

Comment: You could edit the answer adding at the end the details